# Error somewhere in code or mysql database. Getting java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to update mysql table, but getting an error

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`todo`.`tasks`, CONSTRAINT `userid` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `users` (`userid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

```
package sample.Database;

public class Const {

    public static final String USERS_TABLE = "users";
    public static final String TASKS_TABLE = "tasks";

    //USERS Table Column Names
    public static final String USERS_USERID = "userid";
    public static final String USERS_FIRSTNAME = "firstname";
    public static final String USERS_LASTNAME = "lastname";
    public static final String USERS_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String USERS_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String USERS_LOCATION = "location";
    public static final String USERS_GENDER = "gender";

    //TASKS Table Column Names
    public static final String TASKS_ID = "taskid";
    public static final String TASKS_TASK = "task";
    public static final String TASKS_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String TASKS_DATE = "datecreated";
}

    public void inserTask(Task task){

        String insert = "INSERT INTO "+Const.TASKS_TABLE + "("+Const.USERS_USERID+","
        +Const.TASKS_DATE + ","+Const.TASKS_DESCRIPTION+","+Const.TASKS_TASK + ")"
                + "VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

        try {
            try {
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert);

                preparedStatement.setInt(1,task.getUserID());
                preparedStatement.setTimestamp(2,task.getDatecreated());
                preparedStatement.setString(3,task.getDescription());
                preparedStatement.setString(4,task.getTask());


                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

error occur when I press saveTaskButton

    saveTaskButton.setOnAction(event ->{
            Task task = new Task();

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            java.sql.Timestamp timeStamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

            String tastText= taskField.getText().trim();
            String taskDescription = taskField.getText().trim();
            if(!tastText.equals("") || !taskDescription.equals("")){

            task.setDatecreated(timeStamp);
            task.setDescription(taskDescription);
            task.setTask(tastText);
            task.setUserID(getUserID());
            }else{

                System.out.println("NOthing added!");
            }

            databaseHandler.inserTask(task);
            System.out.println("Task created successfully");
        });
```

Adding schemas
[tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I82X2.png)

[users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTzXo.png)

Comment: does the user you are adding exist in your user table?

Comment: user does exist. My thinking there is problem with mysql table. I use mysql workbench to work on them. Same code same tables run fine at my home PC. if that helps. However I'm going to double check it tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I created static value for my class and was able to solve the problem.
passed that value to

```
task.setUserID(AddItem.UserID);
```